# Struct vs class memory overhead

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

I'm writing an app that will create thousands of small objects and store them recursively in array. By "recursively" I mean that each instance of K will have an array of K instances which will have and array of K instances and so on, and this array + one int field are the only properties + some methods. I found that memory usage grows very fast for even small amount of data - about 1MB), and when the data I'm processing is about 10MB I get the "OutOfMemoryException", not to mention when it's bigger (I have 4GB of RAM) :). So what do you suggest me to do? I figured, that if I'd create separate class V to process those objects, so that instances of K would have only array of K's + one integer field and make K as a struct, not a class, it should optimize things a bit - no garbage collection and stuff... But it's a bit of a challenge, so I'd rather ask you whether it's a good idea, before I start a total rewrite :).

EDIT:
Ok, some abstract code

```
public void Add(string word) {
    int i;
    string shorter;

    if (word.Length > 0) {
        i = //something, it's really irrelevant

        if (t[i] == null) {
            t[i] = new MyClass();
        }

        shorterWord = word.Substring(1); 

        //end of word
        if(shorterWord.Length == 0) {
            t[i].WordEnd = END;
        }

        //saving the word letter by letter
        t[i].Add(shorterWord);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me already when researching deeper into this I had the following assumptions (they may be inexact; i'm getting old for a programmer).  A class has extra memory consumption because a reference is required to address it.  Store the reference and an Int32 sized pointer is needed on a 32bit compile. Allocated always on the heap (can't remember if C++ has other possibilities, i would venture yes?)

The short answer, found in this article, Object has a 12bytes basic footprint + 4 possibly unused bytes depending on your class (has no doubt something to do with padding).

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/231120/Reducing-memory-footprint-and-object-instance-size

Other issues you'll run into is Arrays also have an overhead. A possibility would be to manage your own offset into a larger array or arrays. Which in turn is getting closer to something a more efficient language would be better suited for.

I'm not sure if there are libraries that may provide Storage for small objects in an efficient manner. Probably are.

My take on it, use Structs, manage your own offset in a large array, and use proper packing instructions if it serves you (although i suspect this comes at a cost at runtime of a few extra instructions each time you address unevenly packed data)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your stack is blowing up.

Do it iteratively instead of recursively.

You're not blowing the system stack up, your blowing the code stack up,  10K function calls will blow it out of the water.

You need proper tail recursion, which is just an iterative hack.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enough memory in your system. Over 100mb+ etc. It really depends on your system. Linked list, recursive objects is what you are looking at. If you keep recursing, it is going to hit the memory limit and nomemoryexception will be thrown. Make sure you keep track of the memory usage on any program. Nothing is unlimited, especially memory. If memory is limited, save it to a disk.

Looks like there is infinite recursion in your code and out of memory is thrown. Check the code. There should be start and end in recursive code. Otherwise it will go over 10 terrabyte memory at some point.

Comment: Oh no, there's end in my code, only it can take a while before program reaches it...

Comment: If there is any recursion in your code, there should be an end. Otherwise it will go on for eternity and will need unlimited number of resources. Make sure your arrays and recursion stops at some point. The problem here seems like your code is going on forever.

Answer (score 0):

Just list your recursive algorithm and sanitize variable names. If you are doing BFS type of traversal and keep all objects in memory, you will run out of mem. For example, in this case, replace it with DFS.

**Edit 1:**

You can speed up the algo by estimating how many items you will generate then allocate that much memory at once. As the algo progresses, fill up the allocated memory. This reduces fragmentation and reallocation & copy-on-full-array operations.
Nonetheless, after you are done operating on these generated words you should delete them from your datastructure so they can be GC-ed so you don't run out of mem.

Comment: Can you enlighten me please...BFS/DFS?

Comment: I'm not doing BFS type traversal. Example: you have word "asdf" - get first letter, pack it in a instance of K (under index 0), do the same on the newly created instance passing it a string "sdf". If the next word to add would be "asdg", then first three letters are ommited, because thay already exist and only "g" is added as another branch after "d"

Comment: @Myles, I was curious as well so I Googled it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search .  I *think* that's what Adrian is referring to.

Comment: One more thing - I always know what is the index of a letter I'm currently adding - for example "a" is 0, "b" is 1, and so on...

Comment: @nienawiedzony how many new string do you create from one string? Is it exponential? Are you replacing one letter at a time with how many others? I mean what are the choices when you replace `f` in `asdf` with `g`g in `asdg`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. I'm not replacing anything with anything - only adding. Hmmm... Code I presented uses tree-like structure, so if you're adding asdf, and asdg, in the second case only letter "g" is added to the same level as "f" (because the string "asd" exists), and nothing gets replaced.

Comment: @nienawiedzony ah so it is exponential growth: asdf->asd->asdg. I'm guessing you also generate asda,asdb, etc... Right? Are you doing a spell checker by any chance? What do you do with these generated words?

Comment: Well one of applications surely can be a spell checker, but it isn't actually :). Right now I try to generate few milion random strings (of random length, let's say 1 - 1000) to push my algorithm to the limits. I thought it might get stuck when searching such a big structure, not on adding :/

Comment: @nienawiedzony I'd say you've found the limit :P Too many strings and you run out of mem.

Comment: But when I use a 10mb file with random strings it also crashes my app. I can't believe it's too many strings :).

Comment: @nienawiedzony nope, but I can see why someone would: not enough context

Answer (score 0):

You can use a better data structure 
i.e. each letter can be a byte (a-0, b-1 ... ). each word fragment can be in indexed also especially substrings - you should get away with significantly less memory (though a performance penalty)